# Changing UIImage with NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

So my ultimate goal for this project is to have a couple images and a `UIImageview` and to have the image change every 10 seconds, I currently have the `NSTimer` set up and the array of images however I don't know how to utilize both the `NSTimer` and UIImage view together. 
So far this is what I have:

In my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
NSTimer *myTimer;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
```

And in my .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.00 target:self      selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)changeImage
{
_images = @[@"Background 3.png", @"Background.png", @"Background 2.png", @"Background 4.png", @"Background 5.png"];

//stuck here, how do I change the image using the NStimer interval????

}
```

So now that you've seen the code, I am having trouble figuring out what should go inside the changeImage method. Just in review what I would like is for the 5 images in the array to cycle every 10 seconds in the UIImage view. I've tried lots of options I just can't fiqure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why was this thumbs downed? Someone has been serial down-voting the hell out of this site lately.

Comment: @John Well, wasn't me, but this is a dupe of a question the guy asked, I think, earlier this morning.  And the guy does not demonstrate even minimal understanding of programming concepts -- he should NOT be writing Objective-C.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736718/changing-uiimage-every-10-seconds

Comment: @Hot Fair point about the dupes, but I think it's a bit harsh saying that someone shouldn't be writing code because they don't understand programming concepts--isn't that the point of this site? To learn how to program?

Comment: @HotLicks Oh that makes sense, I completely missed that.

Comment: I wouldnt say he should not be writing objective-c. No one should say that

Comment: @GregPrice - Why not?

Comment: Idk. objective-c is probably a more fun place to start than scheme/lisp like I did or whatever other god awful useless intro course the majority of cs departments offer

Comment: @GregPrice - One should learn to program before taking up Objective-C.  One should understand pointers and classes and objects and control structures, at least at a very basic level.  Starting with Objective-C one is apt to "learn" all sorts of incorrect concepts.

Comment: @HotLicks Know what you mean, however, the basic concept of a pointer isn't all that daunting. Modern objective-c is as high of a level language as any. He might run into some lower level problems if he tries hacking into core audio or some other c api but most of iOS is probably pretty safe for newbies. "incorrect" concepts might be subjective in this case. I think two years ago I might be onboard with your argument but how friendly iOS development has become leads me to my opinion

Comment: @GregPrice - Just saw another thread where the OP clearly didn't understand the significance of arrays.  Yet he was trying to write Objective-C code more complex than the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this using the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _images = @[@"Background 3.png", @"Background.png", @"Background 2.png", @"Background 4.png", @"Background 5.png"];
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.00 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)changeImage
{
  static int counter = 0;
  if([_images count] == counter+1)
  {
      counter = 0;
  }
  imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:counter];

  counter++;
}
```

Comment: Remember to reset the counter back to zero if it gets to equal to _images.count - or just access the array using (counter % 5).

Comment: @DavidDoyle: I was editing, when you put the comment :) Anyway thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Midhun MP this is good, its starting to work, however its only switches once then stops, how can i make it continue?

Comment: @user2600115: are you using the above code ? If yes, then it should work. Because I'm resetting the counter in the if condition

Comment: @Midhun MP ye, I have implemented the exact code however its not cycling, it just it once, and is it possible to have it fade in?

Comment: @user2600115: I fixed that bug, please check

Comment: @Midhun MP sorry, but it still dosen't work?

Comment: @user2600115: Please NSLog the counter and check whether it is looping or not

Comment: got it, i know this is a seperate question however i was wonder if it would be possible to fade in the images too?

Comment: @user2600115: There is no direct methods to do this, however, you can use UIView 's animation block for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Put this in changeImage

```
imageview.image = [_images objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
if (self.currentIndex == (_images.count-1)) {
    self.currentIndex = 0;
} else {
    self.currentIndex++;
}
```

and this in .h

```
@property (assign) NSInteger currentIndex;
```

also in viewDidLoad er something set this:

```
self.currentIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this, I would recommend user the `userInfo` property of your `NSTimer`, instead of keeping a static variable. This way you don't have to worry about keeping track of a separate count variable, you can just start it and it will run (though you might want to keep track of it anyway, for other reasons):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _images = @[@"Background 3.png", @"Background.png", @"Background 2.png", @"Background 4.png", @"Background 5.png"];

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.00 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] repeats:YES];
}
```

Then your callback:

```
- (void)changeImage: (NSTimer *)timer
{
    int index = timer.userInfo.intValue;

    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:index];

    timer.userInfo = [NSNumber numberWithInt: (index + 1) % _images.count];
}
```