# How to make fast presentation of images in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found the way to generate movie from a bunch of images ([iOS: How to generate a video file via images/audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373932/ios-how-to-generate-a-video-file-via-images-audio)). But this is not an option for me. I want to present images from iPhone Photo Library in high speed (~0.2 secs per photo) without movie generation. Is it possible?

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983882/assetwriterinput-for-making-video-from-uiimages-on-iphone-issues. It works fine, but takes time to generate video with 100(or more) images. I want to allow user to start demonstration without delay, by presenting pure images without video generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this meets your speed requirement or even works but here goes:

cf/ [Trying to change a UIImageView each 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371100/trying-to-change-a-uiimageview-each-10-seconds)

```
// more likely you will use a for loop to build this array
// (point is, make an array of images that you want to show)
NSArray *imagesToAnimate = @[imageOne,imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour ... imageN];

int numImages = [imagesToAnimate count];
double refreshInterval = 0.2;

// because 1 / (SECONDS/ IMAGE) = IMAGES / SECOND

double desiredFPS = 1/refreshInterval;

imageView.animationImages = imagesToAnimate;

// because IMAGES / (IMAGES / SECOND) = SECONDS

imageView.animationDuration = numImages/desiredFPS;

[imageView startAnimating];
[imageView stopAnimating];
```

Having never used the `animationImages` I don't know how it performs - I don't see why it wouldn't but maybe you have to do some low-level stuff to have the images "ready to go" instead of doing a read for each refresh. I would think though that the folks who designed this library would have done some performance tuning but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIImageView`'s [animationImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages) property :